# Clojure REPL and workflow

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Coming from Haskell, my usual workflow would be to `:l <file name.hs>` on ghci and use the functions and ADT that I have there.

Right now I am using `lein repl` on a typical `lein new app project` context. I have created a `testing.clj` file next to my `core.clj`. There I defined a couple of functions, a protocol and a record implementing the protocol. I was able to use the function by `(use 'testing.testing :reload)` the problem is that I am not able to use the actual record:

```
(def c (Something. 0))
```

I get:

```
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve classname: Something
```

So, what would be the a "better" workflow in this case? Where I don't want to set the functions, protocols, records directly on the REPL, but also I don't want to rely on my core.cls file? I just want a file where I can dump a bunch of stuff and play with it.

PS: My env is Mac OSX Terminal + Sublime

**Edit:** After a couple of minutes I was able to load the record by:

1. `(load-file <file name>)`
2. `(import 'testing.testing.Something)`

I mean, for sure there is a better way than this... :/ I just want to load everything. On the other hand I am able to use the protocol methods the record implements.

Comment: Do you want `load-file`? https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/load-file

Comment: @Kevin added an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the convenience function that is automatically defined for creating records? In this example it would be `(->Something 0)`.

`(Something. 0)` is using the Java constructor, which requires importing the Java class separately. The Java class is created automatically when you define a record to allow Java interop with things you've defined in Clojure.

Using the `(->Something 0)` syntax is the correct way to go and should be possible after you `(use 'testing.testing :reload)`.

**Edit** Given the above didn't seem to help, here's some step-by-step instructions to get a minimal working example

1. You have an app directory `testing` created with `lein new app testing`
2. In `testing/src/testing` you create `testing.clj` containing the following two lines

   ```clj
   (ns testing.testing)
   (defrecord Something [n])
   ```
3. Run `lein repl` from within your project directory
4. Use the namespace with `(use 'testing.testing :reload)`
5. `(:n (->Something 42))` will create an instance of `Something` and retrieve the value of its `n` member - in this case 42.

Comment: `CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: ->Something in this context`